# Java: Compare and replace char from the string

Tags: java

I would like to get a string from user. Loop throught all its chars and check if it contains any "a". If it does, replace those "a" chars with "9".

I get the following error: `"Incompatible operand types char and String"`

How can I fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a string");
        String t = in.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
            if(t.charAt(i) == "a") { // ERROR HERE
                t.charAt(i) = "9"; //HOW ASSIGN NEW CHAR?
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: `'a'` and `'9'` - notice the difference between `"` and `'`.

Comment: `System.out.println(t.replaceAll("a", "9"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. `char` literals are written with `'`, not `"` (`"` is for *string* literals), so you need `'a'`, not `"a"`, in your `if` condition:

   ```
   if(t.charAt(i) == 'a') {
   ```
2. Strings are immutable in Java, you can't replace a character in a string. You have to create a *new* string with the change.

You can do the second one using [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) and concatenation (`+`). For instance:

```
t = t.substring(0, i) + "9" + t.substring(i + 1);
```

Another way is to use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)):

```
t = String.join("", t.substring(0, i), "9", t.substring(i + 1));
```

or even

```
t = String.join("9", t.substring(0, i), t.substring(i + 1));
```

but that last could be a bit confusing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a character with a string, so change to:

```
if(t.charAt(i) == 'a')
```

For the 2nd problem: you cannot assign a new char to a position of the string. 
You can use a `StringBuilder` which is the most efficient way when it comes to multiple replacements like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Type a string");
String t = in.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(t);

for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
    if(t.charAt(i) == 'a') { 
        sb.setCharAt(i, '9'); 
    }
}
t = sb.toString();
```

Here you use the `StringBuilder`'s method `setCharAt()` to change the char at the position you find each `'a'` and after all the replacements are done, you assign to the string `t` the changed string of the `StringBuilder`.